# "Don't have a second email address?" VS "Do you not have a second email address?"

Tags: grammaticality, formality, readability

As a section heading we can have either:

OPTION 1:

Tip: Don't have a second email address?

That's OK, you can create a new one **here**.

OPTION 2:

Tip: Do you not have a second email address?

That's OK, you can create a new one **here**.

Is it OK to use partial sentences in business writing? I think OPTION 2 is grammatically correct but harder to read?

Comment: "Business writing" covers a wide range of things: friendly emails to close colleagues; messaging about corporate social events that aims to be casual and enthusiastic; elaborate formal documents aiming for maximum dignity; legal writing and contracts; all kinds of advertising, PR, and social media conversations. This degree of formality would be fine in a user guide that aims at a casual tone, but it's certainly not very formal.

Comment: FWIW, we ended up using "Do you need a second email address?". We remember, in their style guide, Microsoft recommended avoiding incomplete sentences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As concerns the second sentence, it is not harder to read, but the connotations that can be read into it are different. Whereas the first sentence is a plain question without connotations, the second is supposed to communicate to the interlocutor that the person asking the question is surprised that they shouldn't have a second email address.

Option 2 is not proper  in business writing, as the rather formal process that is a rule in this domain precludes the intermingling of fact with personal feelings.

Comment: FWIW, we ended up using "Do you need a second email address?". We remember, in their style guide, Microsoft recommended avoiding incomplete sentences.